# Spring Boot displaying http requests to index but not any other mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http, gradle

Spring Boot displaying HTTP requests to index path but not any other mapping.

I have created a spring boot application that runs on localhost:8060. The problem is that when I run localhost:8060 on the browser, it works but when I run any other request it says 'There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Access Denied'. In the logs it says that it found the correct method i.e. it mapped correctly but still throws this error.

Greetings.java

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

/**
 * Main application to launch spring boot.
 */
@RestController
public class Greetings {

    /**
     * Main application to launch spring boot.
     */
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/testing123")
    public String indextest() {
        return "Testing";
    }
}
```

ServerApplication

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;

/**
 * Main application to launch spring boot.
 */
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableAsync
public class ServerApplication {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServerApplication.class);

    /**
     * Start the Spring Boot application.
     *
     * @param args command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args);
        logger.info("Sample Application started with context {}", context.getDisplayName());
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
# Initialize feature service.
# This flag should be set ONLY in environments where ss-backend isn't running - normally - ss-backend is set as the
# leader so that it can control (via UI) setting any and all features.
feature.service.is.leader=true

logging.level.org.springframework.web: TRACE


security.ignored=/**
security.basic.enable: false

spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration
```

So it does diplay "Greetings from Spring Boot!" when i go to localhost:8060 but throws the error on localhost:8060/testing123

Comment: Can you try with class leve mapping? Or specify context path server.servlet.context-path on application properties

Comment: Could you give me an example of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you main class `ServerApplication` is in another package which is base package for spring boot application.

But controller `Greetings` is in different package which is not sub package of main class, By default spring boot application load all class that are annotated with any stereotype annotation from the `sub packages` of the base package as `spring` beans into `ApplicationContext`

Use `@ComponentScan` on `Main` class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableAsync
@ComponentScan({"com.vmware.skyscraper", "com.skyscraper.vdisizer"})
public class ServerApplication {

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServerApplication.class);

/**
 * Start the Spring Boot application.
 *
 * @param args command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args);
    logger.info("Sample Application started with context {}", context.getDisplayName());
  }
}
```

Comment: It throws an error "error: cannot find symbol
@ComponentScan({"com.vmware.skyscraper", "com.skyscraper.vdisizer"})
"

Comment: add import statement @SiddhantShah `import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;`

Comment: I moved both the files to the same package, still not working

Comment: Did you restart server after moving to same package?